# Change npm default caret(^) in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

How do I change the default prefix character (`^`) that `npm` inserts in `package.json` when I run `npm install --save package`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`npm config set save-prefix='~'` sets your default back to tilde

`npm config set save-prefix=''` will remove the auto-prefixing

Comment: In my experience `npm config set save-prefix=''` doesn't seem to do anything. I need to pass `--save-exact` but I think it depends on the exact version of npm in use and I don't want to run all the tests to determine exactly which versions have which features/behaviors.

Comment: Interesting observation, it seemed to work for me on `1.4.23`

Comment: Any idea how to get it back to the default? I've tried every combination I can think of - `^`, `^^`, `'^'`, `'\^'`, `''` etc. and nothing seems to work.

Comment: It seems that 4 carets (or more) gets it back to default - `^^^^` - I only discovered this through trial and error / frustration. I'd be interested to know if anyone could explain that!

Windows 10 / NPM 4.0.2

Comment: I'd recommend [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) to help lock dependencies instead of changing the symbols in your `package.json`. It's a much better way of accomplishing the same thing I was trying to capture with the Q/A.

Comment: @Moo the reason for four carets is because the npm command itself is a cmd script.  So the shell takes the four carets and de-escapes them to two carets.  Two carets now go into the cmd script and applied to the command line for node.exe as a single caret.  Alternative as mentioned below, is to double quote it

Answer (score 9):

You should use double quotes to escape the prefix properly:

```
npm config set save-prefix="^"
```

Answer (score 3):

If `npm config set save-prefix='~'` is not doing anything, it's because `save-exact` is set to `true`, thus overwriting it. So in that case, enter the following steps in `terminal`:

1. `npm config set save-exact=false`
2. `npm config set save-prefix='~'`, or to whichever `save-prefix` value you like.

You can confirm that all those changes are saved by entering `npm config list`.

Answer (score 2):

On `windows10` `(npm v. 3.8.6)` I had to omit the quotes by using below command:

```
npm config set save-prefix=~
```